# PHP Storing a date in my SQL for an appointment

Tags: php, sql, date

This is easy and i did search for it and I gotn really complicated answers or things that didn't match my question exactly it's really simple

I have the date

$day = "Jaunuary 8th 2014 5:00pm";
I got this date from a POST from a forum, the user can only select a few dates and time so the value is controlled.

What is the best way to INSERT day and time?

like this? 04-18-2011 or 20091228 for day and what about time?

When I retrieve this information the goal is so i can sort it by time and date so that i can print it out in ORDER OF date

I should probably INSERT date and time together as one variable correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why complicate things?

MySQL has the syntax of "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" for timestamps. Luckily, PHP's date function can handle this quite well:

```
// the POST variable you retrieved, converted to a time via strtotime(), then converted to a date via date()
$appt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['appointment_datetime']));
```

PHP's `date` and `strtotime` functions are smart enough to interpret everything correctly and translate it to the format you need to INSERT into MySQL:

```
"INSERT INTO someTable (AppointmentDate) VALUES ('$appt');"
```

Then, when you retrieve it from the DB, you reformat it (showing the basic `mysqli` syntax rather than using proper binding, just for ease of explanation):

```
$appt = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT AppointmentDate FROM someTable;");
while($apptRow = mysqli_fetch_array($appt,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo date('F j, Y g:i a',strtotime($apptRow['AppointmentDate']));
}
```

This will echo the "plain english" version of the dates. This is obviously simplistic, you would likely capture it into a variable and display appropriately, but you should get the gist. You can consult the [PHP date function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to learn the appropriate symbols you can use, if you want to have a different format.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: wait just so i get this clear  
$string = 'January 8th 2014 5:00pm'; // this is just for reference
$storeDateForSQL = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($string));

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO `date` VALUES '{$storeDateForSQL}'

correct

Comment: i just added that in there to replicate the string you were sourcing. ideally you would have already captured the value into a variable, or you can just use the post variable, i.e. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['appointment_datetime']))`.

Comment: and don't thank me, thank the checkmark if it solved your issue. ;)

Comment: quick question so how do i convert "2014-01-07 14:00" to words?

Comment: that was the last example i gave, you just need to do `date('FORMAT',strtotime('INPUT'))`, where input is your date. you can check the php `date` documentation to know what values translate => http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. For example, format `'F j, Y g:i a'` translates your given date to `'January 7, 2014 2:00 pm'`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39291/discussion-between-artsir-and-planttheidea)

Comment: sorry, i cant ... at work. looks like SO doesn't allow PMs either. sorry boss.

Comment: but if they go in as 'January 7, 2014 2:00 pm' will it sort in SQL correctly?

Comment: no, u need to format it correctly using PHP prior to insert. upon retrieval from the DB u can then reformat it back to the "plain english" version using the same method.

Comment: how do i format it correct? how do i make it a unix time stamp i guess is the better question?

Comment: i gotcha use strtotime twice, i didn't realize the numbers were considered a string

Comment: the `strtotime` function basically will accept any input and treat it as a string ... implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Store a Unix Timestamp and then you can display it in any format you like

```
$ts=time();  // Store that value in an INT (11)
```

Then you can display it like

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a",$YourStoredTimestamp);   // eg March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
```

Comment: how do i convert January 14th 2013 to a UNIX time stamp to store?